# Behavior when connecting a laptop to an HDMI screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

I have a three year old Dell Vostro 3750 (Nvidia Optimus) which I am fairly happy with. Since I will use the computer much more in the future, I would like to use it with an external monitor. I have tested to connect the computer with HDMI to an external monitor, but it doesn't seem to work as I would like.

As I would like it to work:
When I connect the HDMI cable with the lid closed, I want the HDMI screen to become my primary screen. (most important). When I connect the HDMI cable with the lid open, it would be desirable if the HDMI screen becomes a "second" screen" (for movie viewing etc).

As it works now: 
When I connect the HDMI cable with the lid closed, I receive a desktop without any panels.
When I connect the HDMI cable with the lid open, the panels disappear from my laptop screen and the panels does not show up on the HDMI screen.

Turning off the laptop screen in the settings doesn't seem to solve the problem.

The laptop screen is 1600x900, the tested external monitor is 1920x1080. My future external monitor will be 2560x1440.
I am using the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

Any recommendations what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "panels"?  Are you referring to extra desktops?

Comment: Mats Eriksson clearly refers to panels of unity. It's hard to misunderstand it.